# How to read Value from one drive read only link excel to vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, onedrive

I need immediate help. trying for 4 days.
I have excel onedrive read only link. how to read a cell value and store it in text box in vb.net. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then post some code so that we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: No I didnt have code. I just want to help making code.I have view only one drive link for excel. But I have to read it and show it in vb.net controlls

Comment: This site is for helping people with code and specific code issues. It isn't for writing code. You'll need to make an attempt. Also, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) to see how this site works.

Comment: I know dot net and already make an excel automation with vb.net. how dont know how to access  view only one drive link for excel in vb.net. I tries with webbrowser it is opening as same in browser. i am seeing values. but i want to read excel and show in label

Comment: any idea pls help